# How do I send a Object Linq sorted List as a parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, winforms, oop

I am trying to make my code more compromised, and use overall less, however currently I'm running into the problem of not being able to send a list of Objects sorted by linq as a parameter.
the problem is in this part of the code:

```
List<Afspraken> dataAfspraken = new List<Afspraken>();

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillListsForLinq();
        loadReceptionData();
    }

        private void fillListsForLinq()
        {
            dataAfspraken = data.getAfsprakenData();
            //here it fills the list with Afspraken objects
        }

private void loadReceptionData()
    {
        private void loadReceptionGrid
            var receptionToFinnish =
                (from AFspraken in dataAfspraken
                 where Afspraken.factuur_betaald == true && Afspraken.volledig_afgerond == false
                 join Users in dataUsers on Afspraken.gekoppelde_klant equals Users.id
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = Afspraken.id,
                     Klant = Users.gebruikersnaam,
                     Betaald = Afspraken.factuur_betaald,
                     Afgerond = Afspraken.volledig_afgerond
                 }).ToList();
            changeDataviewReception(receptionToFinnish);
        }

        private void changeDataviewReception(List<Object> listData)
        {
            dgvReceptionData.DataSource = listData
        }
```

the Afspraken class looks like this

```
        public class Afspraken
    {
       
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool bevestigd { get; set; }
        public DateTime datum { get; set; }
        public int gekoppelde_klant { get; set; }
        public int gekoppelde_monteur { get; set; }
        public string benodigde_hadelingen { get; set; }
        public decimal totaalprijs { get; set; }
        public bool klaar { get; set; }
        public bool factuur_betaald { get; set; }
        public bool volledig_afgerond { get; set; }
        public string opmerkingen { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I get *receptionToFinnish* as a parameter into *changeDataviewReception*?

Comment: "code more **compromised**" - I suspect you mean *compact*

Comment: For what it's worth, see also https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=finnish%20vs%20finish

Answer (score 0):

`receptionToFinnish` will be a list full of objects of an anonymous type. But your method requires a `List<object>`. This is now allowed since a list is not a variant type.

Say for example that you have a list of bananas and want to give it to someone that wants a list of fruits. This will not work since that other person might try to add an orange to the list of bananas.

To fix this, cast the values to `object` explicitly, for example:

```
select new
{
    Id = Afspraken.id,
    Klant = Users.gebruikersnaam,
    Betaald = Afspraken.factuur_betaald,
    Afgerond = Afspraken.volledig_afgerond
} as object
```